# Sliced Invoices Client Area extension: Adding a reorder button

Tags: php, wordpress

How to add a reorder button in Sliced Invoices Client Area?
Below is a solution on adding a button that the customer can click on their invoice table to order it again.

Answer (score 0):

This solution adds a reorder button for invoices **with status "paid"**. To show the button for all statuses, just remove the *if* condition.

1. Add a new Contact Form 7 contact form with the following fields:

```
[hidden your-email default:user_email]

[hidden your-name default:user_login]

[hidden inv-number default:shortcode_attr]

[submit "Reorder"]
```

2. Open `\wp-content\plugins\sliced-invoices-client-area\public\templates\client-area.php`

   and scroll down to:

```
 <?php
 $count = 0;
 foreach ( $invoices as $invoice ) {
 $class = ($count % 2 == 0) ? 'even' : 'odd'; ?>

 <tr class="row_<?php echo $class; ?> sliced-item">
 <td class="id hidden"><?php echo esc_html( $invoice ); ?></td>
 <td class="date" data-order="<?php echo esc_attr( sliced_get_created( $invoice ) ); ?>"><?php echo sliced_get_created( $invoice ) ? esc_html( date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), sliced_get_created( $invoice ) ) ) : __( 'N/A', 'sliced-invoices-client-area' ); ?></td>
 <td class="due" data-order="<?php echo esc_attr( sliced_get_invoice_due( $invoice ) ); ?>"><?php echo sliced_get_invoice_due( $invoice ) ? esc_html( date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), sliced_get_invoice_due( $invoice ) ) ) : __( 'N/A', 'sliced-invoices-client-area' ); ?></td>
 <td class="title"><?php echo esc_html( get_the_title( $invoice ) ); ?></td>
 <td class="status"><span class="<?php echo sanitize_title( sliced_get_invoice_status( $invoice ) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( sliced_get_client_label( sliced_get_invoice_status( $invoice ), __( sliced_get_invoice_status( $invoice ), 'sliced-invoices' ) ) ); ?></span></td>
 <td class="number"><?php echo esc_html( sliced_get_prefix( $invoice ) . sliced_get_number( $invoice ) ); ?></td>
 <td class="totals"><?php echo esc_html( sliced_get_invoice_total( $invoice ) ); ?></td>
 <td class="actions text-right">
 <a href="<?php esc_url( the_permalink( $invoice ) ); ?>" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><?php echo sliced_get_client_label( 'client-viewinvoice-label', 'View Invoice' ); ?></a>
 <?php if (sanitize_title( sliced_get_invoice_status( $invoice ) ) == 'paid') {?> [contact-form-7 id="XXX" title="XXX" inv-number="<?php echo esc_html( sliced_get_prefix( $invoice ) . sliced_get_number( $invoice ) ); ?>"]
 <?php }?> 
 </td>
 </tr>

 <?php $count++; } ?>
```

where this was added after the view invoice link:

```
<?php if (sanitize_title( sliced_get_invoice_status( $invoice ) ) == 'paid') {?> [contact-form-7 id="XXX" title="XXX" inv-number="<?php echo esc_html( sliced_get_prefix( $invoice ) . sliced_get_number( $invoice ) ); ?>"]
<?php } ?>
```

Just replace the XXX with your form ID and title. 
Now you will receive an email notifying (if you set your form up correctly) a customer wants a reorder, with the invoice number that they have presser the reorder button from.

You can style the button with some basic css to add padding etc.

Cheers,
Phoebe